# LXTerminal doesn't open in Lubuntu

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, lxterminal

Whenever I press the shortcut keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for LXTerminal, a blank terminal window flashes and disappears.

Comment: If you have search, you can try out the other terminals by searching terminal. Then you can map the one that works to your shortcut keys (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I merely renamed my ~/.config file to .config.bak and then logged out.  The resulting creation of the new .config file enabled the use of Ctrl+Alt+t to open the default terminal.  Warning however:  All configurations that you had previously created will also be eliminated so if you have spent time creating them.  You may just want to live with launching the terminal in some other manner such as via the menu or with Run.  Your choice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess it would be fine to open the terminal window form the taskbar itself rather than creating a new configuration.

Comment: Of course.  You could open it from the menu or Run as well.

Comment: Re. your [touchpad issue](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2432565) over at Ubuntu Forums, you maybe interested in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798

Answer (score 0):

I managed to narrow down the solution described by Rex, so we don't lose all our other configurations. In the file:

```
~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/desktop.conf
```

It was the line:
`terminal_manager/command=lxterminal`

which I changed back to the default:
`terminal_manager/command=x-terminal-emulator`

Logout/login required. Now the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> opens the terminal and it stays open.